# Why does $1/0.5$ equal $2$?

Tags: fractions

I would like to know, in  $1/0.5 =2$ why does $1/0.5$ yield $2$.

I want to know a conceptual explanation, not merely a method how to get the answer.

If you are able to explain this in example using image that would be super helpful!

My understanding is if you divide one whole pizza we get $2$ halves slice of pizzas which is $1/2$. So, $1/0.5 = 2$ mean you will get $2$ whole pizza?

Comment: How many halves make one whole?

Comment: Start with 0.5 times 2.  What is that?

Comment: $\frac1{0.5}$ is the same as $\frac{10}5$.

Comment: Because by the definition of $0.5$ we have $2\cdot0.5=1$.

Comment: You are getting downvotes for no good reason, in my opinion. I have upvoted.

Comment: Your question is perfectly fine. Although to some all sorts of questions need to be picture perfect but that isn't how a discussion should be. I've upvoted it

Comment: It's reopened now

Comment: I edited the question a bit. I think your last version was alright, but the very first version was not very clear. While corrected quickly this can still have consequences down the road as the post gets send into a review loop and it's an uphill battle then. It is quite likely that this was already asked earlier in  a similar form but that's a separate concern. You had asked why you got downvotes, that's hard to know. At first it might have been the lack of clarity. Then a dynamic can unfold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to understand what fractions are and what they mean intuitively. 
[This](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/arithmetic-home/arith-review-fractions) might act as a good beginning.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2178452/671231) discussion on Maths SE is quite helpful but goes a bit beyond what you require I think.

Multiple ways which might feel intuitive to you (specific to the question you asked)-

1. How many halves of a cake do you require to make a full cake? (An illustrative example of what [Imranfat](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/64546/imranfat) mentions in the comments)
2. If you have two glasses half filled with water what happens if you put them in one glass? 
   **Or conversely** how many glasses of water which are half filled are required to fill a glass of water?

Answer (score 3):

If I say $6/2$, I ask for the number of times that the number $2$ fits into $6$. The answer is $3$, because I can add $2$ three times to get $6$, i.e. $2+2+2=6$. This is the same as saying that $2\cdot 3 = 6$.

So the answer to $6/2$ is the number with the property that when multiplied by $2$ (the denominator), I get $6$ (the numerator).

The same is true for $1/0.5$. The answer is the number with the property that when multiplied by $0.5$ (the denominator), I get $1$ (the numerator). So I need to figure out what number I can multiply by $0.5$ to get $1$. Or how many times $0.5$ fits into $1$.

Since $0.5+0.5=1$, the answer to $1/0.5$ is $2$. Or saying the same thing in a different way, because $0.5\cdot 2 = 1$, the answer to $1/0.5$ is $2$. The number $2$ is the number with the property that when multiplied by the denominator ($0.5$), I get the numerator ($1$).